# Limit access to user who liked a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to give users access to my service only if they liked my customer's facebook page. I have a single FB APP (mixed PHP/JS) for several services and thus I need to check several pages.

Sadly *user_likes* permission cannot be used for this purpose. Reading [FB's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3)

> FORBIDDEN Gate access to your app, or some content within your app based on whether or not someone has liked a page.

I still would like to offer my service only to users who liked the customer's page, possibly by using a single facebook app. Is this possible in some way?

Of course the problem is not to detect when the user presses the like button, I already accomplished that by the `edge.create` event. The problem is to understand if the user already liked the page when the plugin is loaded. I tried using jQuery but the like box is rendered into an iframe on a different domain so it's XSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It´s not allowed according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) (and the page you mentioned, and the changelog).

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

- It´s not possible anymore, because you would need to get `user_likes` approved and you will not get it approved for something that is not allowed.

Meaning, even if you would find a solution, the main point is that it is not allowed - so don´t do it.

Comment: And now that you told us about it there is even less reason to try to go around the policy